# 405 Method not allowed with Guzzle POST request in PHP

Tags: php, rest, post, laravel-8, guzzle

I'm stuck since several hours on a the consumption of a locale API (which I created) with PHP and Guzzle on a laravel project (8.7).

I've created deux differents laravel projects on the same local server. One is providing some API routes and the second one consume it.

On the first project (which providing APIs) I've created several routes to create, read, update and delete datas from my database.

To access this API routes we need to first consume an API route called "login". This one handle the creation of a token according to a given couple email/password.

This token is needed to call all the others API routes.

The /api/login API is a POST request with email and password datas.

**/api/login route declaration :** (I would like to specify that this route is into the api.php file into my laravel project so the corresponding url is : http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/site/public/api/login)

```php
Route::post('login',[AdminController::class,'index']);
```

**Index method for /api/login :**

```php
    function index(Request $request) 
    {

        if(!($request->ip() == "xxx.xxx.x.xxx")) {

            Log::alert('Ip ' . $request->ip() . ' a tenté de se connecter à l\'Api');

            return response([
                'message' => ['Authentification failed']
            ], 403);
        }

        $admin = Admin::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if (!$admin || !Hash::check($request->password, $admin->password)) {

            return response([
                'message' => ['Email-password couple is incorrect']
            ], 403);
        }

        $token = $admin->createToken('my-app-token')->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'admin' => $admin,
            'token' => $token
        ];

        return response($response, 201);

    }
```

In my second project I'm using Guzzle to consome my APIs.

**/articles route declaration : (http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/backoffice/public/api/login)**

```php
Route::prefix('articles')->group(function () {
    Route::any('/', [ArticlesController::class, 'index'])->name('articles-index');
});
```

**Index method for /articles :**

```php
    public function index() {

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $request = $client->request('POST', 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/site/public/api/login/', [
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
            'form_params' => [
                'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'dAvG454aquysla4'
            ],
            'debug' => true,
        ]);
        $response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
       
        return view('articles.index', [

        ]);
    }
```

I'm getting this error :
`GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException Client error: 'POST http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/site/public/api/login/' resulted in a '405 Method Not Allowed' response: <!doctype html> <html class="theme-light"> <!-- Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: Th (truncated...)`

I don't understand where is my mistake...
The /api/login is correctly define in POST http method and works perfectly with Insomnia.

Does anyone have an idea or will be able to help me using Guzzle? It's the first time I'm using it.

I'm used to consume API with fetch (ajax) in JS.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Try removing last `/` from your url. POST requests usually does not automatically redirect to urls without trailing `/`

Comment: That was good! Sometimes it's so simple it's frustrating ! Thanks a lot @Justinas